# How to add CSRF token for Ajax Request not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, csrf

I want to send some data from the javascript file to the views file in my Django app using an Ajax request. However I am doing this using only Javascript as I am not familiar with jQuery and don't now how to add the CSRF token.

Here is my Javascript Code:

```
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/list");
    var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

    let data = {
        items: JSON.stringify(items)
    }
    request.setRequestHeader( 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrftoken);
    request.send(data);
```

I have tried using `Cookies.get('csrftoken')` and `getCSRFTokenValue()` but am unsure how to send the token once acquired.

In the Developers' Console it says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: `request.setRequestHeader( 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', theToken );`

Comment: It still says forbidden (csrf token missing or incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a form tag within it you have to added the csrf_token so you have to add a decorator just before your view

```
@csrf_exempt 
Def your_view(request):
```